# Convert str to unicode in python

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

Good day!
I'm having trouble with decoding text to unicode.
I need to convert str which is equal to

```
    '\u4038' # or something like that
```

in ASCII and I need to convert this string to ONE unicode symbol. Can you please explain< how to do that?
The

```
    len(unicode('\u4038'))
```

prints 6, so this is not a solution:(

If it's needed, the resulting symbol is cyrillic at the most cases.

Comment: Do you mean you have a string `'\\u4038'` ?

Comment: Why do you have this string? Where does it come from? What do you see if you print it? If this is coming from JSON, you want the [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module.

Comment: If you need `unicode-escape` then something is broken in your data pipeline. Find the source of `'\u4038'` and fix it instead of using `unicode-escape` encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean you have a string `'\\u4038'`, you can use [`unicode-escape` encoding](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings):

```
>>> s = b'\\u4038' # == br'\u4038'

>>> print(s)
\u4038
>>> len(s)
6

>>> print(s.decode('unicode-escape'))
䀸
>>> len(s.decode('unicode-escape'))
1
```

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a better way, but here is one:

```
In [27]: s = r'\u4038'

In [28]: len(ast.literal_eval('u"' + s + '"'))
Out[28]: 1
```